# Getting 2 different li tags in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a menu in laravel 5.4. The problem I'm having is because of my code if my menu item has a seo attached to it then my link is
inside the li tag, but because of this if my menu item doesn't have a seo attched to it I just have a link that isn't inside an li tag. I'm not
sure how to go about doing it so that I can get the link inside the li tag regardless of if there is a seo or not.

As it stands in my firebug this is how my menu looks

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main_menu" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse menubar" id="main_menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">
          <li class="parent ">
            <a href="http://localhost/writers-circle/public/home.html">home</a>
          </li>
          <a href="http://localhost/writers-circle/public/3">stories</a> <!-- HERE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS -->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

menu.blade.php

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main_menu" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse menubar" id="main_menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">
        @foreach($menus_child as $grandfather)
          @foreach($grandfather->seo as $seo)
            <li class="parent {!! (current_page($seo->url)) ? 'current' : '' !!}">
          @endforeach
            {!! Html::link(getSeoLink($grandfather->id), $grandfather->title) !!}
            </li>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I hope I made sense in my question.

Comment: Why you not made menu in your controller and pass them to view as two different variable

Answer (score 0):

I GOT IT!!!. The problem was actually in my helpers.php file. I finally managed to get it to work.

This is what I did in my helpers.php file

```
function menu_active($id){

        $test_id = $id;
         $testing = App\Modules\Menus\Models\Menu::with('seo')->where('id', $test_id)->first();
         $seo_url = $testing->seo;

         foreach($seo_url as $t){
            $url = $t['url'];
            if(is_array($url)){
                return in_array(Request::path(), $url) ? 'current' : '';
            }

             return Request::path() == $url ? 'current' : '';
         }

        if(is_array($id)){
            return in_array(Request::path(), $id) ? 'current' : '';
        }

        return Request::path() == $id ? 'current' : '';
    }
```

and then I changed my ul in my menu.blade.php to look like this

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">
        @foreach($menus_child as $grandfather)
          <li class="parent {!! menu_active($grandfather->id) !!}">
            {!! Html::link(getSeoLink($grandfather->id), $grandfather->title) !!}
          </li>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
```